# Detect if Android MediaPlayer is stalled or not?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am using Android MediaPlayer to render a video from remote URL in android app. But I want to show a ProgressBar when the video stops due to the lack of buffered data present in a slow network and hide the ProgressBar when the video starts playing again.

Can anyone please tell me which listener and which method I need to use to show or hide the ProgressBar based on the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this callback of `MediaPlayer`

`mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
 mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
 mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);`

Comment: How do I know from these listeners that the video is stopped due to lack of buffered data and then video  starts playing again? Can you give a code example?